# Ruby is already using the class name of my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, namespaces, conflict

I'm making a forum application with various levels of authorization, one of which is a Monitor.  I am doing this by extending my User class, and I plan on fine tuning this with "-ship" classes (e.g. administratorship, authorship, moderatorship, etc.).  Apparently the Monitor class is part of ruby [mixin](http://apidock.com/ruby/MonitorMixin).  How do I keep my resource name without the collisions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- avoid the `require 'monitor.rb'` call which is pulling in the standard Monitor instance
- do some runtime magic to rename the existing Monitor class.
- monkey with your load path so that `require 'monitor.rb'` pulls in an empty implementation of Monitor.

But in all cases you could end up with the situation where a 3rd party library is using Monitor expecting it to be the standard Monitor class. So, I'd advise against any of the above.

I'd say your only two reasonable options are:

A) you could put your class in a namespace:

```
Module MyApp
  class Monitor
    #...
  end
end
```

if your app uses some kind of auto-require magic (e.g it's a rails app) then you would put your implementation in /my_app/monitor.rb. When you wanted to refer to that class you would do something like `my_monitor = MyApp::Monitor.new()`, or whatever.

B) you could use a different class name :)

Comment: As mentioned above (MyModule::), how would I go about referencing these classes after I've implemented them?  I've read some about modules and mixins before but I've never used a custom one I've made in an app.

Comment: I edited my answer to include more details on the namespacing approach. Hope that makes it clearer for you.

Comment: Nice, I like suggestion B too...  I will try this and accept if it works out OK.

Comment: It seems as though Tony isn't right.  The new module does not take precedence in the cascade.  Option B is looking better and better...

Answer (score 2):

Declare your Monitor class in other module.

```
module MyModule

  class Monitor

  end

end
```

Comment: You don't need the `MyModule::` if you are namespacing the class.

Comment: And put this file under _app/models/my_module/monitor.rb_

Comment: Should I do this with all of the User children?  Also, shouldn't the module class be inheriting from User (e.g. class Monitor < User)?

Comment: @ryan So lets say I was going to call this module Hierarchy, you are telling me to put my model in app/models/hierarchy/monitor.rb and that will work?  Why would I still need this file if it is defined in the module?

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I just found a neat trick (errr, hack) to get around this which may work.

I work on a large legacy application which, unfortunately, has a "Fixture" model which is quite important and which is used everywhere.  When running tests, it's impossible to create a Fixture instance because of the Fixture class used by ActiveRecord when running tests.  So I did the following:

```
FixtureModel = Fixture.dup
```

This freezes my class in place so that I can refer to it later (but just in my tests!) without being extended by the ActiveRecord Fixture class (which is not namespaced)