# conflicting ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, conflict

I need to use two gems in my project that both claim the PDF namespace:  pdf-reader and htmldoc.

Is there any way to get them to play nice together?  The only way I can think of is to rewrite my own version of htmldoc to give it a different namespace.

Comment: +1 good question. This is a nasty problem that I don't have an easy fix for. It begs the question why you need both to read PDFs but I am sure you have your reasons.

Comment: What error messages does it give?

Comment: It's *probably* possible to do a rewrite, given that you can build and install your own gems locally.

Comment: @EnabrenTane: "begs the question" - people keep using that phrase. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: I came across similar questions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736747/how-to-resolve-rails-model-namespace-collision and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694333/ruby-is-already-using-the-class-name-of-my-model

Comment: @EnabrenTane: it's because I need the htmldoc gem to generate PDFs, and the pdf-reader gem to determine the number of pages in a generated PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably no elegant solution to the problem. If you really need the two gems working side by side I think your best option is to fork one of them (or possibly both) and use your fork. This is how I'd go about it:

- If either gem is hosted on Github then fork it, or if both are on Github fork the one that seems to be the least work.
- If neither gem is on Github, see if you can get hold of the source (grabbing it from the gem is a possibility, but finding the real repository might be helpful as there may be other files there that are not included in the gem), and put it in a repository on Github. Make sure the gem's license allows this (which it almost certainly does if it's one of the common open source licenses).
- Make your changes.
- Make sure there is a `.gemspec` file in the root of the repository, the next step will not work otherwise.
- Use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to manage your projects dependencies. Instead of specifying the dependency to the library you've modified as

  ```
  gem 'the_gem'
  ```

  specify it like this:

  ```
  gem 'the_gem', :git => 'git://github.com/you/the_gem.git'
  ```

  (but change the URL to the repository to the actual one)
- Send an e-mail to the maintainer of the gem you modified and ask him or her to consider merging in your changes in the next release.

Bundler makes it really easy to use alternative versions of gems with minimal hassle. I often fork gems, fix bugs or add features, change my `Gemfile` to point to my version, then ask the maintainer to merge in my changes. When, or if, that happens I simply change my `Gemfile` back to just refer to the official version of the gem.

An alternative strategy, if the maintainer does not want to merge in your changes and you want to distribute your version to others is to push up your version to Rubygems as a new gem, but in that case prefix the gem name with your name, or some other string that identifies your gem as a variant.

Comment: This is the way I decided to go.  Original is on github: https://github.com/craigw/htmldoc, I forked and created: https://github.com/jemminger/namespaced_htmldoc

Answer (score 5):

Basically, there's nothing you can do. It is good practice in Ruby, to use *distinctive* names in the top-level namespace *precisely* for this reason, and you just happened to stumble upon two libraries that violate that practice.

One thing you *could* do is to use `Kernel#load` instead of `Kernel#require`. `Kernel#load` takes an optional boolean argument, which will tell it to evaluate the file within an anonymous module. Note, however, that this is in no way safe: it is perfectly possible to *explicitly* put stuff in the top-level namespace (using something like `module ::PDF`) and thus break out of the anonymous module.

Note also that the API is really crappy: `load` simply returns `true` or `false`, just like `require` does. (Actually, since `load` *always* loads, it *always* returns `true`.) There is no way to actually *get* at the anonymous module. You basically have to grab it out of the `ObjectSpace` by hand. Oh, and of course, since nothing actually references the anonymous module, it will be garbage-collected, so not only do you have to rummage around in the bowels of `ObjectSpace` to *find* the module, you also have to *race* the garbage collector.

Sometimes, I wish Ruby had a proper module system like Newspeak, Standard ML or Racket.

Comment: And not all Ruby implementations have `ObjectSpace`, do they?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: I'm not sure about IronRuby, but JRuby has at least the relevant bits to do `ObjectSpace.each_object(Module)`, even though it does not have a full implementation of `ObjectSpace`.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of a new piece of functionality called refinements. It's designed to avoid two different monkeypatches affecting the same class causing problems, but I'd see if it could help with your problem.

Comment: Come one, there's not even a working prototype implementation of refinements. Suggesting that he should look at something like that is as helpful as suggesting that he enlist the help of fairies and unicorns.

Comment: @Theo: According to [this blog post](http://timeless.judofyr.net/refinements-in-ruby) , it only takes three lines to install the refinements patch. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: "There are some implementation details which might need to be resolved" (from the same post). Patch the Ruby interpreter... are you seriously suggesting that as a solution?

Comment: I was seriously suggesting he check if it's a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in linked
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37311072/292780

Respectfully disagree with the answer above. Here is how I do it:

`ruby -S gem list my_gem`

```
`*** LOCAL GEMS ***
my_gem (1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.0.2)
`
```

`ruby -S gem lock my_gem-1.0.0 > locklist.rb`

which generates list of dependencies for a specific version into locklist

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'my_gem', '= 1.0.0'
gem 'gem_base', '= 1.0.0'
gem 'rest-client', '= 1.7.2'
gem 'savon', '= 1.1.0'
gem 'addressable', '= 2.3.6'
gem 'mime-types', '= 1.25.1'
gem 'netrc', '= 0.11.0'
```

now you can do `load('locklist.rb')` which will load a specific version of a gem along with its dependencies. Look ma, no Bundler.