# Google API(ruby) causing gem conflict errors

Tags: ruby, cucumber, google-api-ruby-client

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a cucumber script:

```
Unable to activate google-api-client-0.9.12, because httpclient-2.6.0.1 conflicts with httpclient (~> 2.7) (Gem::ConflictError)
```

I have three versions of httpclient:

```
httpclient (2.8.2.2, 2.6.0.1, 2.3.4.1)
```

All have other dependencies, I've tried deleting individual versions. 
e.g.

```
You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    httpclient-2.6.0.1

rally_api-1.2.1 depends on httpclient (= 2.6.0.1)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    httpclient-2.3.4.1

calabash-android-0.4.21 depends on httpclient (~> 2.3.2)
calabash-cucumber-0.9.169 depends on httpclient (~> 2.3.3)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    httpclient-2.8.2.2

google-api-client-0.9.12 depends on httpclient (~> 2.7)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
```

How can I get the google API to work with my existing code?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're using bundler. I suggest writing a Gemfile that includes all of the gems you need (without nonessential version specifications) and seeing whether bundler can find a set of mutually compatible versions.

Comment: This is the closest that I could find:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579465/managing-conflicting-versions-of-ruby-gems

Did some more digging into my dependencies and it turns out I'm not actually using the older versions and was able to delete them.