# Superclass conflict in two gem dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm adding 2 gems to Gemfile:

```
gem 'ethereum'
gem 'nem-ruby', require: 'nem'
```

`bundle install --path vendor/bundle` works just fine, however when I am trying to run `bundle exec rails c` (or any other `bundle exec`) I've got error:

```
 superclass mismatch for class Digest::SHA3 (Digest::Class is given but was Digest::Base) (TypeError)
```

In Gemfile.lock I see the following:

```
 ...
 ethereum (0.5.2)
      activesupport
      sha3-pure-ruby (= 0.1.1)
 nem-ruby (0.0.12)
      base32 (~> 0.3)
      digest-sha3 (~> 1.1)
      faraday (~> 0.11)
      faraday_middleware (~> 0.11)
...
```

As far, as I understand, this error is caused by the digest-sha3 and sha3-pure-ruby dependencies. They both have Digest::SHA3 class, but one of them inherits [Object](https://github.com/phusion/digest-sha3-ruby/blob/2d2d1d2d7afe2e1e0b2a0938870f7614959c8551/lib/digest/sha3/version.rb#L2) and other [Digest::Class](https://github.com/havenwood/sha3-pure-ruby/blob/8e301c9d1584b0444e5bb9f1af1d898550109547/lib/sha3-pure-ruby.rb#L5).

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do much with it.

You can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4497478/6745294

Comment: I've must overlooked this question (