# Put gem class into namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

To my Rails Gemfile I added a new gem. It is used like this:

```
Email::Client
```

The issue I'm having right now is that I also have a class in my rails app that's called `Email`. Now sometimes when I try to initialize it I get the following error:

```
Email.new # >> undefined method 'new' for Email:Module
```

Probably because `Email` is a `Module` in the gem. How can I fix this issue? Is there a way to namespace the gem module? I don't want to rename my Email class.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to rename the Email-Class.

Yet this is what you'll have to do. Your code is the only thing you control. Either rename/alias it (`MyEmail`) or namespace it (`MyApp::Email`).

Btw, you got off easy this time. Imagine what'd happen if the other `Email` was also a class. Suddenly, all your methods are gone. You add or change a method and your email doesn't see it. This could make for a frustrating debugging session.

Comment: `require: false` in gemfile, or `EmailModel = Email.dup` in the initializers would help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140516/6548745

Comment: `require: false` will only delay the problem. The gem will be required _eventually_ (else why include it at all) and will cause name clash _then_. Not sure about your `dup` proposal, what is it for? You can simply alias by `EmailModel = Email`, but if we do that, why not just go and rename the model?

Comment: I edited to share the reference, and if aliasing works then isn't it better than migration?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Migration is not necessary, we can keep the table name (although now it can't be guessed and needs to be specified explicitly). But yeah, we can alias instead.

Comment: yep, namespacing is also an option instead of migration.